# property type based on enum value in a sibling

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an enum and an interface

```
enum A {
   X, Y, Z
}

interface Test {
   a: A
   b: ???
}
```

The type of b should be dependent on the value of `a` and be mapped to `B1`, `B2`, `B3` depending whether `a` is `X`, `Y` or `Z`.

What I want to achieve is that typescript would complain if I define an object like so:

```
const x: Test = {
   a: A.X,
   b: {...} // this should complain if values are not in B1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union...

```
 type Test = { a: A.X, b: B1 } |
      { a: A.Y, b: B2 } |
      { a: A.Z, b: B3 }
```

Comment: any idea how I could make Test an interface and not a type?

Comment: @AndreasHerd I don't think there is a way to do it in interfaces yet.